# How to add class depending on route | Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink

I have some problems with getting current path of url, when user changes the route by clicking the link on the navbar module. How to get current url path every time when user clicks on route links on the navigation module. I need to get it on navigation.ts script. There what I have now:
TS:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.router.events.subscribe(res => {
    if (this.router.url == "/buy") {
      this.navExpand = true;
    }

    else {
      this.navExpand = false;
    }
  });
}
```

It works but every time it loops 8 times. I am working on angular 6

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: I have some problems with getting current path of url, when user changes the route by clicking the link on the navbar module.

Comment: you could do the same in ngOnInit which will ne invoked only once when the directive is instantiated

Comment: @JoelJoseph won't change a thing, the issue is with the observable, not the lifecycle hook.

Comment: @trichetriche yes you are right , thanks for correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the router is subject to several events.

Try filtering on the last event, `NavigationEnd` :

```
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe(res => {
    if (this.router.url == "/buy") {
      this.navExpand = true;
    }

    else {
      this.navExpand = false;
    }
  });
```

Imports :

```
import { filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: Thank you brother. You saved my time. :)

Comment: @bek no problem, glad I could help ! If you feel this helped you, feel free to upvote, and if it resolved yur issue, consider closing your question !